# How can I delete renderer from OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

If I'm creating new renderer using the following code (taken from http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geolocation-orientation.html)  ,

```
map.beforeRender(function (map, frameState) {
        if (frameState !== null) {

            // use sampling period to get a smooth transition
            var m = frameState.time - deltaMean * 1.5;
            m = Math.max(m, previousM);
            previousM = m;
            // interpolate position along positions LineString
            var c = positions.getCoordinateAtM(m, true);
            var view = frameState.viewState;
            if (c) {
                view.center = getCenterWithHeading(c, -c[2], view.resolution);
                view.rotation = -c[2];
                marker.setPosition(c);
            }
        }
        return true; // Force animation to continue
    });
```

How can I disable / delete it when I want to stop this rendering ?

****** Solution ********

```
map.beforeRender(function (map, frameState) {
//console.log (disable_render);
if (disable_render === true) return true;

if (frameState !== null) {
    // use sampling period to get a smooth transition
    var m = frameState.time - deltaMean * 1.5;
    m = Math.max(m, previousM);
    previousM = m;
    // interpolate position along positions LineString
    var c = positions.getCoordinateAtM(m, true);
    var view = frameState.viewState;
    if (c) {
        view.center = getCenterWithHeading(c, -c[2], view.resolution);
        view.rotation = -c[2];
        marker.setPosition(c);
    }
}
return true; // Force animation to continue
```

});

Comment: global variable?  if (disable_render) return; at the beginning of your function?

Comment: Isn't there a way to remove code ? Better performance than just checking if statement every iteration. ...

Comment: perhaps describe in a bit more detail what you're trying to do. would you like a way to stop the map from following the geolocation?  you could have another button or link that sets a variable that you check inside the function geolocate() to not execute the window.setTimeout (that calls geolocate again)

Comment: I want to be able to PAN the map manually ... which means stopping the auto tracking.